# how to solve Uncaught TypeError:this.state.books.map is not a function error

Tags: dictionary

how to solve Uncaught TypeError:this.state.books.map is not a function

```
const List =(props) =>(
<tr>
    <td>{props.list.Book_Name}</td>
    <td>{props.list.Book_ISBN}</td>
    <td>{props.list.Book_Author}</td>
    <td>{props.list.Book_Price}</td>
    <td>{props.list.Book_PublishYear}</td>
    <td>{props.list.Book_Publisher}</td>
</tr>
);
export default class ViewBooks extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={books:[]};
}
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/book/all').then((res)=>{
        this.setState({books:res.data});
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
bookList()
{
    return this.state.books.map((book,i)=>{
        return <List book = {book} key={i}/>

    })

}
```

i cannot retrieve value from db.its give an error as Uncaught TypeError:this.state.books.map is not a function

Comment: I think res.data is undefined or not an array, have you try console.log the res.data?

Comment: Check what "res.data" is, as suggested above. If it's an array, your code looks okay, but depending on what the API gives back you may need to do some parsing of your own first.

Comment: I will try.Thank you for the reply

Comment: res.data is undefined.How can solve this?The url is working fine in postman.